# Disable button with checkbox in table

Tags: javascript

I have an array of data on which each row has a checkbox which the user can check to select a row.
I want to make it so that if no row is selected, the "delete" button will be disabled.

The button gets disabled on page load, and the checkbox on row 1 works as planned, but if the table contains 2 or more rows the rest don't.

This is what I have so far:

```
<button class="btn btn-default modal-opener" id="chkboxdelbtn" onchange="toggle();" type="button" type="submit">Delete Selection</button>

<?php 
    $row = get_member_tskey_info($mysqli);
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($row as $r){
        echo '<tr><td style="padding-right:0px;">';

        if (($i<=2) && ($r['status'] == 1)){        
            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="keyselect[]" id="keyselect[]" value="' . $r['uid'] . '" /></td>';                                                
        }else{
            echo '<input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" value="" /></td>';
        }
        ...
```

Javascript:

```js
document.getElementById('chkboxdelbtn').disabled = true;
function toggle() {
    if (document.getElementById('keyselect[]').checked == true) {
        document.getElementById('chkboxdelbtn').disabled = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('chkboxdelbtn').disabled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware for the duplicate ID's on your `checkbox`. It cannot happen. Actually, you wouldn't even need an id to the checkbox, as you can make your `toggle()` function much simpler with `querySelectorAll()`:

```
function toggle() {
    document.getElementById('chkboxdelbtn').disabled = 
       ( document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length <= 0 );
}
```

This will look for all input checkboxes that are checked, and see if there's at least one. If not, it get's disabled.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll

Answer (score 2):

IDs have to be unique. Use a class instead.

```
foreach ($row as $r){
    echo '<tr><td style="padding-right:0px;">';

    if (($i<=2) && ($r['status'] == 1)){        
        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="keyselect[]" class="keyselect" value="' . $r['uid'] . '" /></td>';                                                
    }else{
        echo '<input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" value="" /></td>';
    }
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementsById('chkboxdelbtn').disabled = true;
function toggle(){
    var keyselects = document.getElementsByClassName('keyselect');
    for (var i = 0; i < keyselects.length; i++) {
        if (keyselects[i].checked == true) {
            document.getElementById('chkboxdelbtn').disabled = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```